# Magento Custom payment method frontend requires JavaScript to be activated only after it is selected

Tags: magento

### Background story

I am building a new payment method. I'm in the process of adding the `frontend` in the checkout page. The payment method require javascript.

So I have managed to add a script to the header of the checkout page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>foo/bar.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

### The problem:

However in my case, `foo/bar.js` bind a DOM element which not yet exists. Hence error in the JavaScript. That DOM element is only added to the page after the buyers reach the payment stage.

One dirty solution is to addJs together with the content, such that the script is executed together. This method however give me a problem that the block [`checkout.payment.methods`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L336-L338) does not have the method `addJs`. If we're to use this approach, what should I do to be able to `addJs` in `checkout.payment.methods` block?

Alternatively, I keep the script at `head` block, and I update my JavaScript to be triggered only when the buyer select my payment method. However I am not sure what JavaScript event is being dispatch if we were to listen on payment method selected. What would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Payment model, that extends from **Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract** you can add new property:

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'form_blockname';
```

Then in your module Block folder, add the Block class in **Package/Module/Block/Form/Blockname.php** and in it add:

```
class Package_Module_Block_Form_Blockname extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('your_template_dir/form/your_template.phtml');
    }
}
```

Then in the **app/design/frontend/base/default/your_template_dir/form/your_template.phtml** file add the JS code you need. This template will be fetched via AJAX and your JS code will fire up when the Payment section opens up. From here you can easily add event on the checkbox that contains your payment method and activate it.
EDIT: The template file JavaScript with the escape characters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        alert('This is your JavaScript Code');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the first things I did. This will not work because phtml somehow remove all `<script>`

Comment: For example when I add the <script> code in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/cashondelivery.phtml it is still being executed. I also added the script in custom payment method form template and still got executed. Maybe try to add //<![CDATA[ before the script code and //]]> after the code ends.

Comment: Yay, It works. `<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ alert('Hello'); /*]]>*/</script>` indeed loaded in `.phtml` file. Could you add this in your answer, because this what makes answer works. I am not sure about the reason, but I guess it's the escape character. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: I have updated my answer. I guess that was the problem. Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add an observer to core_block_abstract_to_html_after and append some javascript to the checkout/onepage_payment_methods block:

```
public function appendSomeJavascript($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if (get_class($block)=='Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods'){

        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $html = $transport->getHtml();  

        $html .= "<script>alert('appended some js');</script>"; 

        $transport->setHtml($html);         
    }        

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The script is executed well at the payment method step. I'm not quite sure, but the script also got executed at the initial page load. How can we avoid it?

Comment: The appended script should not do any thing on load except call your script in the head that contains the logic for your method. For example, <script>myHeadScriptObj.doSomething();</script>

Comment: Yes, that's what was done. Because the appended script is the same for both call, it call the script in the head twice. first call when the checkout page loaded, second call when the payment method section loaded. Unless we could somehow listen to another observer which only triggered when payment section is loaded. (I'm not sure why when I trace the checkout page initial load, the payment section was called triggering the appended script but with no payment methods in it)